# Office 2010 converts pptx to pdf differently on windows7 and XP

Tags: pdf, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

Office 2010 has this built-in "create pdf" function.

```
File->Save & Send->Create PDF/XPS Document
```

I created a pptx file in win7, then converted it to win7.pdf.

then I copied the pptx to xp and converted it to xp.pdf

these 2 pdf files are different in size at first glance.

then I used ICEpdf to convert the 2 pdfs to image, then compared the 2 images on every pixel.

```
for(int i=0;i<width;i++){
         for(int j=0;j<height;j++){
                final int color1=img1.getRGB(i,j);
                final int color2=img2.getRGB(i,j);
                if(color1!=color2){
                    identical=false;
                }
                diffImage.setRGB(i,j,color1^color2);
            }
        }
```

then I saved the diff image to disk, it looked like this: [image]

PS:

- I'm pretty sure it's not a font problem, because I have tried several fonts.
- It's not a problem of my program or ICEpdf, because if I compare them in Adobe Reader(zoom in enough) I can see the difference.

Why office 2010 converts the same pptx to pdf differently on different machines? 
Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem (if it's a problem, though I don't exactly understand why it would be) is that the characters are positioned slightly differently between the two versions?

PowerPoint relies on the local printer driver for font metrics; I'm guessing that what you're seeing is a difference between printer drivers.